# NullReferenceException was unhandled using stored procedures

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I cant seem to solve the problem with my code:

```
public BindingSource getDataSource(string user_name)
    {
        string query = "Select user_name from UserPass_table where user_name Like @user_Name + '%' ;";
        BindingSource bindSource = new BindingSource();
        if (this.connect())
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter dA = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
                {
                    using (DataTable DT = new DataTable())
                    {
                        dA.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_Name", user_name);
                        dA.Fill(DT);
                        bindSource.DataSource = DT;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Number.ToString());
                bindSource.DataSource = null;
            }
        }
        this.close();
        return bindSource;
    }
```

when I ran this code: it says System.NullReferenceException was unhandled at this line of code

```
dA.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_Name", user_name);
```

Comment: Obviously, your `dA.InsertCommand` is null. You have to initialize it first.

Comment: how? i mean dont seem to get it :D. can you help me?

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is a common situation for programmers. The link provided should help you understand the problem. Then use the debugger to find what/where/when you have a variable that is `null`.

Comment: the answers with the link doesnt seem to fit my needed answers. can you suggest on what part of the code should I change?

Comment: @Reyn, after brief review of your code it seems to me your line of code `dA.InsertCommand.Parameters` should be `dA.SelectCommand.Parameters`.

Comment: And I was about to post an answer, damnit ;)

Comment: thanks! will do try it. can I anytime ask you guys if any error arrives? :D